# Github Desktop unwanted file duplication

Tags: github, github-desktop

I'm uploading a website I've built onto Github, via Github Desktop (mac).
For some reason, every one of my files is being duplicated on upload.

If I have 5 files to upload, Github will try to push 10. The content of the duplicate files is blank, except for the text: 
**Mac OS X  2°âATTRâxThis resource fork intentionally left blank ÿÿ**

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing in the Github Desktop app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMuvK.png

Note that there are two of almost every file. I've removed my CSS and JS folders to reduce clutter - it duplicates all of that content as well.

I've never encountered this issue with GitHub Desktop before. The location of my project does not have duplicates - only on Github Desktop do these show up. Perhaps the 'resource fork' sentence on these duplicate files is a clue?

My Github: http://www.github.com/kylevassella

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be some files generated by mac os. See more information here:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/14981

You can avoid them by creating a git ignore `.gitignore` file at the root of your project and add the following line

```
._*
```

git will ignore all the file beginning by `._`

more about gitignore here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: I went into terminal and did a **touch .gitignore** in the appropriate location - are you saying I need to do **touch .gitignore ._*** instead? Thanks a lot for the reply.

Comment: Just create a file named .gitignore and add ._* at the first line. So in command line you could do `touch .gitignore && echo "._*" > .gitignore` or just use your favorite text editor.